Netopeer2-cli subscribe notifications to get changed values along with xpath
I'm using netopeer2 library and running netopeer2-cli and netopeer2-server on separate machines.
I'm subscribing to the config change notifications from netopeer2-cli using subscribe rpc.
The subscribe rpc gives only xpath information of the nodes and not the values changed.
I not only want the xpaths of the changed leaf nodes, but also the values which are updated. And I'm not getting that with the current implementation of subscribe rpc in netopeer2-cli.
Can anybody tell how to get the actual changed values in the form of notifications?
I have tried the subscribe rpc that gives only xpath list where the changes have occurred on netopeer2-server side sysrepo.
Here is a sample of the output of netopeer2-cli side of the subscribe rpc:
<netconf-config-change xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-netconf-notifications">
  <changed-by\>
    <username>root</username>
    <session-id>0</session-id>
  </changed-by\>
  <datastore>running</datastore>
  <edit>
    <target xmlns:xyz">*xpath of some node*</target>
    <operation>create</operation>
  </edit>
  <edit>
    <target xmlns:xyz">**xpath of some node**</target>
    <operation>create</operation>
  </edit>
</netconf-config-change>

Also for establish-sub rpc, what I understood is we will get periodic notifications with the subscribed xpath. But I want notifications only on changes to the leaf nodes.

You seem to be describing dynamic on-change YANG Push notifications.
netopeer2 claims compliance to RFC8641, RFC8640 and RFC8639:

RFC Compliance


 RFC 5277 NETCONF Event Notifications



 RFC 6022 YANG Module for NETCONF Monitoring



 RFC 6241 Network Configuration Protocol (NETCONF)



 RFC 6242 Using the NETCONF Protocol over Secure Shell (SSH)



 RFC 6243 With-defaults Capability for NETCONF



 RFC 6470 Network Configuration Protocol (NETCONF) Base Notifications



 RFC 7589 Using the NETCONF Protocol over Transport Layer Security (TLS) with Mutual X.509 Authentication



 RFC 8071 NETCONF Call Home and RESTCONF Call Home



 RFC 8341 Network Configuration Access Control Model



 RFC 8525 YANG Library



 RFC 8526 NETCONF Extensions to Support the Network Management Datastore Architecture



 RFC 8639 Subscription to YANG Notifications



 RFC 8640 Dynamic Subscription to YANG Events and Datastores over NETCONF



 RFC 8641 Subscription to YANG Notifications for Datastore Updates




So you should be able to use establish-subscription to get what you need. Provided that the YANG module set on the server-side contains the ietf-yang-push module and has the on-change YANG feature enabled.
An example RPC:
  <establish-subscription xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-subscribed-notifications">
    <datastore xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-yang-push"
               xmlns:ds="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-datastores">ds:running</datastore>
    <datastore-subtree-filter xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-yang-push">
      <if:interfaces xmlns:if="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">
        <if:interface/>
      </if:interfaces>
    </datastore-subtree-filter>
    <on-change xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-yang-push"/>
  </establish-subscription>

Example notification:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<notification xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:notification:1.0">
  <eventTime>2024-06-11T09:37:10+02:00</eventTime>
  <push-update xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-yang-push">
    <id>2147483648</id>
    <datastore-contents>
      <interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">
        <interface>
          <name>x</name>
          <type xmlns:ianaift="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:iana-if-type">ianaift:gigabitEthernet</type>
          <admin-status>up</admin-status>
          <oper-status>up</oper-status>
          <last-change>2024-06-11T09:36:02Z</last-change>
          <if-index>1</if-index>
          <phys-address>00:00:00:00:00:01</phys-address>
          <speed>1000000</speed>
          <statistics>
            <discontinuity-time>2024-06-11T09:36:02Z</discontinuity-time>
            <in-octets>4009744</in-octets>
            <in-unicast-pkts>4154</in-unicast-pkts>
            <in-broadcast-pkts>3632</in-broadcast-pkts>
            <in-multicast-pkts>4439</in-multicast-pkts>
            <in-discards>24</in-discards>
            <in-errors>23</in-errors>
            <in-unknown-protos>27</in-unknown-protos>
            <out-octets>3693110</out-octets>
            <out-unicast-pkts>5255</out-unicast-pkts>
            <out-broadcast-pkts>3455</out-broadcast-pkts>
            <out-multicast-pkts>2840</out-multicast-pkts>
            <out-discards>22</out-discards>
            <out-errors>37</out-errors>
          </statistics>
        </interface>
      </interfaces>
    </datastore-contents>
  </push-update>
</notification>

Followed by:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<notification xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:notification:1.0">
  <eventTime>2024-06-11T09:37:12+02:00</eventTime>
  <push-change-update xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-yang-push">
    <id>2147483648</id>
    <datastore-changes>
      <yang-patch>
        <patch-id>0</patch-id>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>1</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/out-unicast-pkts</target>
          <value>
            <out-unicast-pkts xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">5638</out-unicast-pkts>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>2</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/in-discards</target>
          <value>
            <in-discards xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">26</in-discards>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>3</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/in-unicast-pkts</target>
          <value>
            <in-unicast-pkts xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">4522</in-unicast-pkts>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>4</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/out-discards</target>
          <value>
            <out-discards xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">27</out-discards>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>5</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/in-octets</target>
          <value>
            <in-octets xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">4291946</in-octets>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>6</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/out-octets</target>
          <value>
            <out-octets xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">4381528</out-octets>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>7</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/in-broadcast-pkts</target>
          <value>
            <in-broadcast-pkts xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">4592</in-broadcast-pkts>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>8</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/in-multicast-pkts</target>
          <value>
            <in-multicast-pkts xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">4879</in-multicast-pkts>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>9</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/out-broadcast-pkts</target>
          <value>
            <out-broadcast-pkts xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">4231</out-broadcast-pkts>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>10</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/in-unknown-protos</target>
          <value>
            <in-unknown-protos xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">29</in-unknown-protos>
          </value>
        </edit>
        <edit>
          <edit-id>11</edit-id>
          <operation>replace</operation>
          <target>/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface=x/statistics/out-multicast-pkts</target>
          <value>
            <out-multicast-pkts xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces">3135</out-multicast-pkts>
          </value>
        </edit>
      </yang-patch>
    </datastore-changes>
  </push-change-update>
</notification>

Note: the examples were not actually generated by netopeer2, but should look very similar.

Hi @predi I got one rpc of netopeer2 called "establish-push" which gives the same response as you have stated.
However it is causing crash to the netopeer2-server while executing assert(xml). I need some help in that.

@SamKore, sorry. I have no knowledge about how netopeer2 works. I do know a thing or two about how it should work, though. You should try the standard establish-subscription RPC instead.

Thanks @predi.
Actually establish-sub RPC as per netopeer2 can provide periodic notifications and not on-change notifications, that's the limitation of it.

@SamKore, do you happen to have a source for that information? Perhaps an issue on their tracker? I'd like to revise the answer, but came up short in my search.

Yes I'm working on it for sometime now. I have raised the issue on their github repo yesterday and communicating on it.
